Is it possible to change the return type of a method based on what is passed in as a parameter?
Is it possible for the same method have different return types based on what is passed in, so that for example GetScripts(new Camera()) returns a Camera and GetScripts(new Cube()) returns a Cube?
I have three classes:
public class Script
{
    
}
public class Camera : Script
{
    
}
public class Cube : Script
{
    
}

I've also got a GameObject class which contains a list of Scripts and these methods:
public void RemoveAllSqripts()
{
    Scripts.Clear();
}
public void AddScript(Script script)
{
    Scripts.Add(script);
}
public Script GetScript(Type type)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < Scripts.Count; i++)
    {
        if (Scripts[i].GetType() == type)
        {
            return Scripts[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

I have code in the main program that looks like this:
GameObject go = new GameObject();
go.AddScript(new Camera());
go.AddScript(new Cube());
Camera camera = go.GetScript(typeof(Camera));

The code line: Camera camera = go.GetScript(typeof(Camera)); doesn't work since GetScript returns a Script, not a Camera.
Is it possible to change the return type depending on what type you pass in as parameter, so that go.GetScript(typeof(Camera)) returns a Camera and go.GetScript(typeof(Cube)) returns a Cube?
I tried using generics for the first time (I don't quite understand them yet) and I figured out that if I rewrote the GetScript() method to something like this:
public T GetScript<T>()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Scripts.Count; i++)
    {
        if (Scripts[i].GetType() == typeof(T))
        {
            return Scripts[i];
        }
    }
    return default(T);
}

it would return the type if it exists in the list. The problem now is that return Scripts[i]; doesn't work, and I don't know why. Guess I need a lesson of how generics work.
I've tried looking at the microsoft documentation, but it didn't help 'cause I only understood half of what was written.
I'm grateful for any help.

Cast the value with return (T)Scripts[i];.

"and I don't know why"  The compiler for sure gives you some error message. Mind to share this with us?

CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Script' to 'T'. This error occurs even if I rewrite it to: return (T)Scripts[i];

Here's a lesson: If you see a compilation error but don't know how to solve it, try searching for it. Usually there are solutions on the internet. If you are still unable to resolve it, please add the complete error message to your question.

Just realised in the second case the error message is: CS0030: Cannot convert type 'Script' to 'T'. Probably it doesn't matter since the two error messages seem to be almost  the same.

@shingo thanks for linking the page. I probably wouldn't have found it. This line made it work: public T GetScript<T>() where T : Script

And then you can change the implementation to public T GetScript<T>() where T : Script => Scripts.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();. Note that that will behave differently in the case where you asked for a base class, and there's an object of a derived class... your code wouldn't return the derived object, whereas OfType will.

Okay wow, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

public static class Extensions {  public static IEnumerable<TResult> OfExactType<TResult>(  this IEnumerable source) {   return source   .OfType<TResult>()   .Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(TResult));  } } should give the same behavior

This worked:
public T GetScript<T>() where T : Script

Thanks @shingo.
Link to solution
